# Constraints on new unknown stable fermions?

Tags: particle-physics, fermions, beyond-the-standard-model

This question is rather speculative, but I would like to ask it anyway. What are the constraints on possibility of discovering new unknown stable fermions of some sort in the future?

If I am not wrong, we can exclude particles lighter than ~400 GeV, otherwise they would already show  in some way in experiments performed so far. Or they would have to interact very little with both our matter and electromagnetic radiation, like axions do. Are there any other strong limits? (on mass, charge, spin, coupling to strong/electroweak sector, etc.)

I am particularly interested in solid constraints, I am aware that according to most standard theories, no new stable fermions are probably *expected*, but I am interested what can we really rule out.

Comment: If a particle doesn't interact trough electroweak or color force, it won't show up in any of our experiments. The standard model can't make any predictions about such particles. In general, I would take any "prediction" based on a model with a grain of salt, nature usually finds a way to thoroughly mock the person who made that prediction.

Comment: Thank you very much! And what about constrains on charged particles? (I do not have any particular model in mind, but I know there is plenty possibilities, like magnetic monopoles or superpartners or others, that are not themselves part of the Standard Model.) Could something new (and stable) still appear at low energies? Could we have missed is in particle accelerators? Sorry if the question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

As CuriousOne mentions in the comment, if the new fermion has no charge under any of the gauge symmetries then it will not interact with anything (except gravitationally) so we barely have any constrains on such particles.

On the other hand, if you are thinking more about the lines of a fermion that is "similar" to $e, \mu$ or $\tau$, but just heavier, then in reality your are asking for the constraints on a fourth generation. It is reasonable to expect that such a fermion would be accompanied by a light neutrino, in the same way that the others do. However, the number of light neutrino families has been measured experimentally to high precision, see for example:
http://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/reviews/rpp2014-rev-light-neutrino-types.pdf .
So this proposition is ruled out.

Therefore, the new fermion will be accompanied by a heavy neutrino (or no neutrino at all). Then you have to explain why this would be the case and the constraints on the new particle will be dependent on the model you propose.

Comment: What about Higgs portals? This answer is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Apart from the completely uncharged particles, how does the situation look, for example, for charged particles that are currently not described by the Standard Model? Fourth generation particles seem to be too specific - is there a reason not to expect any other charged fermions except for copies of electron or neutrino?

And what about criterion on the stability? I guess fourth generation particles would be unstable, right?

Comment: Yes, they would be extremely unstable. If they are heavier than the top quark the will have a lifetime of less than  5×10−25 s.

Answer (score 0):

In supersymetry every particle from the standard model has a superpartner. But photons, gluons and W-and Z-bosons don't have photinos, gluinos, winos ,and zinos as superpartners but neutralinos which are a bit of  photinos,gluinos winos ,and zinos. The lightest neutralino which is a fermion is probably stable. They probably are neutral, have no color charge and interact by the weak interaction.
They also interact through gravity. They could be a component of dark matter. There are 3 other neutralinos but they are unstable. Their mass is unknown.